# How can I update a jsonb field partially with typeorm in postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am using [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) as ORM library to connect to postgresql database. I saved a few columns as `jsonb` type. Now I need to support update a json data partially, for example,

```
{
firstName: xx,
lastName: xxx
}
```

If I only update `firstName`, I don't want to override lastName in the update statement. `postgresql` supports `json_set` which I can use to update the field partially but how can I make it work with `typeorm` libraray?

Answer (score 4):

Since jsonb datatype is specific to PostgreSQL you will need to use Postgres-specific raw SQL.

How to use raw SQL for update is explained under [raw-sql-support](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/update-query-builder.md#raw-sql-support) in the TypeOrm documentation. For example:

```
    await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update(User)
        .set({ jsonbColumn: () => "raw SQL jsonb function here" })
        .where("id = :id", { id: 2 })
        .execute();
```

Refer to `jsonb_set` under [json functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) in PostgreSQL documentation for how to replace part of jsonb data:

```
jsonb_set(jsonbColumn,'{first_name}','"new first name"')
```

Putting it together, it will look like this:

```
let id = 2;
let pathText = '{first_name}';
let newValue  = '"new first name"';
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .update(User)
    .set({ jsonbColumn: () => "jsonb_set(jsonbColumn," + pathText + ",'" + newValue + "')" })
    .where("id = :id", { id: id })
    .execute();
```

Those quotes needed by json and jsonb_set make this very awkward, and if your new name contains embedded " or ' it will mess up.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all - `await entityManager .createQueryBuilder() .update(UserSettings) .set({appSettings: ``jsonb_set(appSettings, '${key}', '${val}')``}) .where('id = :userSettingsId', {userSettingsId: userSettings.id}) .execute() ` gets turned into `UPDATE "user_settings" SET "app_settings" = $1 WHERE "id" IN ($2) -- PARAMETERS: ["{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",16180]`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the previous reply:
If you want to add new fields as well you may try:

```
let keyName:string = '{key2}'
let valueName:string = '"new_value"'

emailLog: () => "jsonb_set(cast(email_log as jsonb), '" + keyNAme + "','" + valueName + "'," + "true" + ")"
```